# Inline Constraint error in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've custom route in my webapi. when i call it, i am getting following error

`The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'MovieData'.`

**Stack Trace:**
`at System.Web.Http.Routing.InlineRouteTemplateParser.GetInlineConstraint(Group constraintGroup, Boolean isOptional, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.InlineRouteTemplateParser.ParseRouteTemplate(String routeTemplate, IDictionary`2 defaults, IDictionary`2 constraints, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.DirectRouteFactoryContext.CreateBuilder(String template, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.DirectRouteFactoryContext.CreateBuilderInternal(String template)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.DirectRouteFactoryContext.CreateBuilder(String template)
   at System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute.System.Web.Http.Routing.IDirectRouteFactory.CreateRoute(DirectRouteFactoryContext context)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.DefaultDirectRouteProvider.CreateRouteEntry(String prefix, IDirectRouteFactory factory, IReadOnlyCollection`1 actions,`IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, Boolean targetIsAction)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.DefaultDirectRouteProvider.CreateRouteEntries(String prefix, IReadOnlyCollection`1 factories, IReadOnlyCollection`1 actions, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, Boolean targetIsAction)`
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.DefaultDirectRouteProvider.GetActionDirectRoutes(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IReadOnlyList`1 factories, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)`
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.DefaultDirectRouteProvider.GetDirectRoutes(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, IReadOnlyList`1 actionDescriptors, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)`
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddRouteEntries(SubRouteCollection collector, HttpConfiguration configuration, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__1()
   `at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(Func`1 initializer)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action`1 configurationCallback)`
   at MoviesAPI.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Users\VinoBharathi\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MoviesAPI\MoviesAPI\Global.asax.cs:line 14`

**ApiController :**
`[HttpGet]`
       `[Route("~/api/Values/GetMovieByCategory/{movieData:MovieData}")]`
        `public IEnumerable<MovieData> GetMovieByCategory(MovieData movieData)`
        `{

            IEnumerable<MovieData> movieDataByCat = null;
            string[] paramCast;
            if (movieData.Cast.Count() != 0)`
                `paramCast = movieData.Cast;

            IEnumerable<MovieData> GetAllMovies = null;

            GetAllMovies = repo.GetAll();`

```
        if (movieData.Cast == null || movieData.Cast.Count() == 0)
        {
            movieDataByCat = from data in GetAllMovies
                             where (data.Classification == (movieData.Classification == null ? string.Empty : movieData.Classification) ||
                                    data.Genre == (movieData.Genre == null ? string.Empty : movieData.Genre) ||
                                    data.Rating == movieData.Rating ||
                                    data.ReleaseDate == movieData.ReleaseDate ||
                                    data.Title == (movieData.Title == null ? string.Empty : movieData.Title))

                             select data;
        }
        return movieDataByCat;
    }`
```

Help me to get over this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement inline constraint named `MovieData` taht inherits from `IHttpRouteConstraint`.
It's declared in your route: [Route("~/api/Values/GetMovieByCategory/{movieData:**MovieData**}")]

Ten register it in WebApiConfig file:

```
  var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
            constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("MovieData", typeof(MovieDataRouteConstraint));
           config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
```